# Proper way to Nest permissions in Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase-security

I have a series of collections

Users --> Portfolio (owner == userID) --> Accounts --> Items

I want to give Accounts and Items the same permissions as Portfolio. My permission for portfolio seems to work and is:

```
 match /Portfolios/{portfolioID} {
  allow read, write, update, delete: if resource.data.owner ==  request.auth.uid;
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

Now what do I do with Accounts? and then Items?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work... I am just unsure how secure the nested documents are:

```
match /Portfolios/{document} {
        allow read, update, write, create, delete: if  resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;

        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, update, write, create, delete:  if request.auth.uid != null;
            allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
    }
```

Any improvements would be welcomed